# Removing duplicates in an SQL database on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I need to remove duplicates from a table that looks like this:

```
id           post_author    post_title
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
21319        1              Youngstown State University
20535        1              Yo San University of Traditional Chinese Medicine
30268        29             Yo San University of Traditional Chinese Medicine
29747        29             Yeshiva University
21964        1              Yale University
29247        29             Yale University
29497        29             Xavier University of Louisiana
21916        1              Xavier University
29862        29             Xavier University
29860        29             Wright State University-Main Campus
20915        1              Wright State University-Lake Campus
21562        1              World Mission University
30267        29             World Mission University
```

Basically, if there are two entries with the same `post_title`, I need to remove the one with `post_author = 1`, but if the `post_title` is unique then the entry should be left as is.

How can this be done with an SQL query?

EDIT:

I've tried a query suggested by Mureinik. The query looks like this:

```
DELETE t FROM wp_posts AS t 
WHERE t.post_author = 1 AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wp_posts s 
                WHERE t.post_title = s.post_title
                AND s.post_authot != 1)
```

But I got error:

```
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this select or delete??

Comment: Is it on mysql or postgresql?

Comment: It's delete, I need to remove duplicates. It's for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a condition on `post_author = 1` where there are more than one `post_title` with a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_del AS SELECT post_title 
                     FROM t 
                     GROUP BY post_title 
                     HAVING count(post_title)>1;               

DELETE FROM t 
WHERE post_author = 1 
  AND post_title IN (select post_title FROM t_del) ;
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49fa0/1)

Comment: You are right, you need a temporary table. This cannot be done in a single SQL. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```
DELETE FROM my_table t
WHERE  post_author = 1 AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table s
               WHERE  t.post_title = s.post_title AND
                      s.post_author != 1)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but got an error. Please, take a look at the updated question. Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With `in` operator:

```
delete from TableName where post_author = 1
and post_title in(select post_title from TableName group by post_title having count(*) > 1)
```